# Using notebook (Databricks) show error java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, databricks

I'm using https://community.cloud.databricks.com/ (notebook) when I try to access Storage GCP through the Python command as below:

```
df = spark.read.format(csv).load(gs://test-gcs-doc-bucket-pr/test)
```

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server at: 169.254.169.xxx/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token
```

Databricks Spark Configuration:

````
spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.client_id "10"
spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.auth_uri "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true
spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable true
spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.email "test-gcs.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.token_uri "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
spark.hadoop.fs.gs.project_id "oval-replica-9999999"
spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.private_key "--BEGIN"
spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.private_key_id "3f869c98d389bb28c5b13a0e31785e73d8b ```
````

Comment: You might want to remove that private key from SO.

Comment: Are you using [GCP Databricks](https://cloud.google.com/databricks)? Your [previous closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68520044/8753991) same as this question, it means you need to update your question, include more details that can help to improve your question.